# LAST CALL for input: Is physical infrastructure on-topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, off-topic

**Tue Dec 31 update...**

Info added to On-topic help page.

**Mon Dec 2 update...**

Do we have ANY nay-sayers? Last call for input! Physical infrastructure looks to become explicitly on-topic.

**Original question...**

When people mention network infrastructure, they generally think about routers/switches. Yet, the problems that I encounter most are ones dealing with the physical nature of networking (cable/fiber). Crappy fiber runs, lack of cable management and bad airflow dynamics, just to name a few.

The Network Engineering topics don't mention anything about physical infrastructure.

Are these on topic?

If not, why?

Comment: If I want to know how to manage our broadband on a specific medium, I'd certainly come to Network Engineering. I absolutely agree with the physical structure being a L1 topic.

Comment: If someone has provided an answer that resolves your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. This will reward both the person who provided the answer and yourself with additional reputation. If you do not do so, your question will periodically get refreshed back to the main page, possibly distracting community members from other questions they may be able to help answer for other users. Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, I think physical cabling would be on-topic

We've had some questions regarding [physical cabling](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=cable).

The ones which were closed would remain off-topic (home networking, vague, etc) even if physical cabling were on topic. That's good; I'm saying it seems we are already allowing physical cabling.

Comment: Would it be worth adding to to the "What topics can I ask about here?"

Comment: Definitely worth while. But first we'll wait a couple weeks to see what the community thinks. I'd like to see someone at least express some constructive criticism before we edit the "what's on-topic" page.

Comment: If we take questions about cabling / racking, I personally think we should strongly encourage a clear picture / diagram that illustrates the problem.  The lack of a picture / diagram could optionally be used as justification to put on hold as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 4):

I think physical layer is clearly 'on topic'.  Its right there at the beginning of the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) and its where most troubleshooting begins.

There are also design discussions such as top-of-rack verse middle-of-row data center designs, stack-able switches verse chassis. etc

Answer (score 3):

Definitely on topic. While generic questions like UTP wiring may seem mundane, think about topics around modular patching, WDM, light switching, etc.